# Python Import functions from higher/other folder

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I am fairly new to Python (3.3.2) and I have minimal experience using

`from .... import ....`

beyond the use of `time`, `turtle`, and `math`. I am working on several Project Euler problems that require a function to determine the primality of a number using my simple isPrime(n) function. The isPrime(n) function is the only function in a file named isPrime.py.

I have a separate folder for each [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problem I attempt to keep my code straight but I find it inconvenient having to copy my isPrime(n) function directly from isPrime.py and paste it into every new file within a folder devoted to each problem. I have some ideas about improving my isPrime(n) function and I don't want to have to open up several of the Problem folders just to change the lines in each file when I make some revisions.

So I thought that writing the following line at the top of each Problem's file would work:

`from isPrime.py import isPrime`
or even `from isPrime import isPrime`

However, I encounter the following error both ways:

`ImportError: No module named 'isPrime'`

Here is a basic description of my folder hierarchy:

1. ProjectEuler Folder

   - Primality Functions Folder

     - isPrime.py [contains the function isPrime(n)]
     - anotherFile.py
     - yetAnotherFile.py
   - Problem X Folder

     - problemX.py
     - something.py
     - somethingElse.py
   - Problem Y Folder

     - problemY.py
     - something2.py
     - somethingElse2.py
   - Problem Z Folder

     - problemZ.py
     - something3.py
     - somethingElse3.py

My question is:

What do I need to type in the opening lines of the files `problemX.py`,`problemY.py`, and `problemZ.py` to use the function `isPrime(n)` from the file `isPrime.py` in the folder `Primality Functions`?

I have searched at length here at stackoverflow and I see many questions are related to Python and difficulty with importing files/modules. However, I don't understand what a system path is, or what a relative import is, and I have no idea what the Python documentation found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) is telling me. **Please do not mark this question as duplicate of the many Python/Import questions already here. All I'm looking for is a simple 1-3 lines of code to place at the top of my files so I can import my functions from other folders** and won't have to copy-and-paste my functions every time I attempt a new problem. I will be most appreciative of the most simply-worded answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you i.e., I had some utility modules that may be useful to solve multiple project euler problems and each project euler problem had its own directory.

Initially I put the utility folder into `sys.path` as [@user3114046 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20821773/4279):

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '../Primality Functions Folder')
from isPrime import isPrime
```

It felt dirty but it worked (note: I even used a relative path here!).

As an alternative, you could create a [simple `setup.py` file](http://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/introduction.html#a-simple-example) in the same directory as `isPrime.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup

NAME = 'isPrime'
setup(name=NAME, version='0.0.1', py_modules=[NAME])
```

and install your utility module:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

after that you could use it in any script:

```
from isPrime import isPrime
```

If you want to use several utility modules; you could put them into `project_euler_utils` directory and install it as Python package. Put `setup.py` along side `project_euler_utils` directory:

```
from distutils.core import setup

NAME = 'project_euler_utils'
setup(name=NAME, version='0.0.1', packages=[NAME])
```

Run `pip install project_euler_utils`, to install it. After that; you could use it from any script/module:

```
from project_euler_utils.isprime import isprime
```

Note: I've used lowercase names as [pep-8 suggests](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) (you need to rename your module and the function in it).

---

> I tried using the fullest path I can think of with `"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Primality Functions Folder"`, it gave me a `Syntax Error: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.`

Use raw string literals for Windows paths `r'C:\Users\Owner...'` (note: `r''` prefix) Otherwise backslash is special inside literal strings, in particular `u'\U0001F385'` is a not 10 characters; it is a [single Unicode codepoint `U+1F385`](http://codepoints.net/U+1F385).

Comment: Thank you @J.F. Sebastian and user3114046 for answers; I'm not sure where to put the line "$ python setup.py install" so I want to pursue the "dirty" way of doing it. However, when I put the full directory path, I tried using the fullest path I can think of with "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Primality Functions Folder", it gave me a Syntax Error:                                     (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape. I also tried putting any path without the leading "C:\" -- still says "No module named 'isPrime'.

Comment: @Xoque55: `python setup.py install` is a command that you run manually  on the command line once for each `isPrime` version. [If you don't know what is command line; here's a primer](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendixa.html)

Comment: @Xoque55: I've updated the answer to explain the `'\U'` error.